# encrypting password using php

Tags: php

I need to encrypt the password and store it in the db. i have added a code 
"$newpass= md5($pass_word);" in php file. but still its not working

```
<?php
$hostname   =   "xxxx";
$username   =   "xxxx";
$password   =   "xxxx";
$dbName     =   "xxxx";
$user_name='';
$pass_word='';
$email='';
$errormsg='';
$subject='';
$message='';
$newpass='';
$conn       =   mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbName);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$user_name=$_POST['usr'];
$address1=$_POST['addr1']; 
$address2=$_POST['addr2'];
$pass_word=$_POST['pswd'];
$newpass= md5($pass_word); 
$email=$_POST['email'];
if(empty( $user_name))
 {
   $errormsg='<br>enter the name S';

 }
if(trim($address1)=="")
 {
   $errormsg="<br>entre the address1 S";
   //echo $errormsg;
  } 
if(trim($address2)=="")
 {
   $errormsg="<br>entre the address2 S";
   //echo $errormsg;
  } 
if(trim($pass_word)=="")
 {
   $errormsg="<br>entre the password S";
   // echo $errormsg;
  } 
if(trim($email)=="")
{
   $errormsg="<br> enter the email S";
   // echo $errormsg;
}
$message="your username is".$user_name."your passwod is".$pass_word;
if(strlen($errormsg)==0)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xxx` ( `id` , `Name` , `Address1` , `Address2` , `password` , `email` )
VALUES (
'', '$user_name', '$address1', '$address2', '$newpass', '$email'
)")or die(mysql_error()); ;
echo $newpass;
echo "you have successfully registered ";

}
mail($email,$subject,$message);
}
?>
```

This is my php page.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some of the code you are using to give us a reference to look at?

Comment: Please explain "not working".  What's not working?  Getting an error, plain text appearing in the database, some other problem?  Also a little code around the part that's not working would make easier to be helpful.

Comment: And explain what is 'not working'? Is it not storing down to the database? Is it not creating the password hash? Is it the login code that isn't working?

Comment: Define 'not working'. Paste more code, read http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html by Eric Raymond

Comment: it is not encrypting the password. it is stored as like it is entered

Comment: Code looks fine. Try to first assign sql query to a variable, echo it, and then execute - this way you could check if password in query is properly hashed.

Comment: So you're saying that when you look in the database, you see the plaintext password instead of the hash of the password?

Answer (score 5):

Something is likely wrong with your input, as the syntax is correct. Though md5 hashing isn't a bad practice, it is relatively insecure on its own. To add a small extra layer of security, I usually do something like this ([hash salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))):

```
<?php

function md5_salted($string,$salt){
    return md5( md5($string) . md5($salt) );
}

$salt = "wQfChpLYWFtiQV8d9Cao";
echo md5('userPassword'); // 221068207e125b97beb4e2d062e888b1
echo md5_salted('userPassword', $salt); // 07d9ffd0115e61fb22f857b7d252339c

?>
```

Worth noting: as others have stated, this is hashing, not encryption. If you're interested in encryption, investigate [TLS/SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Answer (score 2):

Well, that would hash the password, not encrypt it.  Hashing is probably what you actually wanted though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, md5 is not encryption, it's a hashing function (more in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)). It could be used to quite safely store it in DB. But usage you've provided is fine, should work. You should elaborate on what does it mean "it's not working".

This code:

```
<?php
$pass = 'secret';
$newpass = md5($pass);
echo $newpass;
?>
```

Outputs to:

```
5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69
```

Comment: Actually I need to encrypt and store the password that user gave during the registration process into the db. I am sorry if i was not clear earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the md5 function provided by the database (mysql) in the sql query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xxx` ( `id` , `Name` , `Address1` , `Address2` , `password` , `email` )
VALUES (
'', '$user_name', '$address1', '$address2', MD5('$pass_word'), '$email'
)")or die(mysql_error());
```

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5

Comment: shouldn't that still be quoted, i.e. `MD5('$pass_word')`?